# W/UploadTask: could not retrieve file size for upload ***** java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not a whole file

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-storage

I have tried so many diffrent methods but the result is always the same, "Not a whole file".
I can't upload images to the FireBase Storage no matter what.
Im returning a blank String just because I want to get the image uploaded first.

```
private String upload_image_to_firestore_db(Uri imagem, String key, String nome_campo, int tamanho) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final StorageReference imageRef = storage_reference.child("imagens/"+ imagem.getLastPathSegment());

        imageRef.putFile(imagem) //ERROR POINTS HERE
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
          
                        Task<Uri> downloadUrl = imageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                        downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String imageReference = uri.toString();
                                if (nome_campo == Imagem_Capa){
                                    reference.child("atividades").child(key).child(nome_campo).setValue(imageReference);
                                }else if (imagensUrlTemp.size()!= tamanho){
                                    imagensUrlTemp.add(imageReference);
                                }else {
                                    reference.child("atividades").child(key).child(nome_campo).setValue(imagensUrlTemp);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Log.d("Upload:","Failed.");
                    }
                });
        return "";
    }
```

This is the error i get.

````
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not a whole file
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1648)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1578)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:124)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:241)
        at com.example.azoresexperience.database.DataBaseHandlerFireBase.upload_image_to_firestore_db(DataBaseHandlerFireBase.java:197)
        at com.example.azoresexperience.database.DataBaseHandlerFireBase.addDataAtividades(DataBaseHandlerFireBase.java:183)
        at com.example.azoresexperience.database.DataBaseHandlerFireBase.adicionarAtividades(DataBaseHandlerFireBase.java:368)
        at com.example.azoresexperience.database.DataBaseHandlerFireBase.run(DataBaseHandlerFireBase.java:96)
        at com.example.azoresexperience.MainActivity$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:271)
        at com.example.azoresexperience.MainActivity$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:223)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)```
````

Comment: Just a quick note: Firebase Storage is not the same as Firestore.  They are different products. I've edited the tags to correct this, but I thought I'd be clear.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of facing this "bug", i learned that I wasn't giving the app enough time to upload, that's why nothing was happening and i was unable to uplaod. As for the error, im able to upload besides still having the same error, meaning, it's kinda irrelevant.